# How to generate an .xctest file for export to AWS device farm

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services

How do you generate a the {MyAppName}.xctest file seen under the products group in Xcode 7? I've tried building for testing targeting a generic iOS Device, adding new targets with unit tests, and building a testing bundle, but I can't seem to find out how to generate these files. I've attempted this using the method outlined in this question: [Building XCTest UI tests for AWS Device Farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442271/building-xctest-ui-tests-for-aws-device-farm).

Answer (score 3):

Do a build targeting a generic iOS device.

In Xcode Navigator scroll down and open your Products folder.

Right-click on [your-project].app file and select - "Show in Finder"

in Finder right-click on the [your-project].app file and select "Show Package Contents"

Open the Plugins folder

Answer (score 2):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

The link to instructions that you mentioned in your question are for XCTest UI and in your question you are looking for .xctest directory.

You would need the .xctest directory if you want to run **XCTest** tests and the instructions for those are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-xctest.html)

If you want to run the **XCTest UI** tests then you will need the *-Runner.app bundler and the instructions for those are different than that for just XCTest. XCTest UI instructions are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-xctest-ui.html)

In general both these folders above can be found under Products directory when you do a build for test.

Comment: I did see those instructions, but I am still having trouble actually generating the .xctest directory / xctest bundle. When building in Xcode I do have a target to build unit tests (not ui tests) but when I build for testing, I can't find where that bundle would have been built to.

Comment: Are you able to locate your Products directory under DerivedData? The xctest directiry will be under there. Did you try doing a grep or 'find' under Derived Data?

Comment: @NikofTime is there any way to limit the (XCTestUI) tests being run to a subset, other than by having one scheme per subset and uploading those?

Comment: @jlew: Unfortunately not yet. Is this something that is blocking you?

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't say blocking exactly, just a factor to consider when deciding between XCTestUI and other supported frameworks.

Comment: Sure thing. I have noted that down as a + 1 for this feature