# Plugins folder missing from iOS App generated using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest, xcodebuild

I want to upload the `TestTarget.xctest` files located in under `MyApp.app/Plugins` directory to Device Farm. ([SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478253/how-to-generate-an-xctest-file-for-export-to-aws-device-farm)).

In the past the Plugins folder was found inside `MyApp.app`, but now I do not see it. So I can't export the .xctest directory.

What build setting might I be missing? My scheme settings are the same as before. This is the command I run to generate the app:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -scheme $SCHEME_NAME -workspace $WORKSPACE_PATH -sdk iphoneos -destination generic/platform=iOS SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS=iphoneos BUILD_VARIANTS=normal GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES -showBuildTimingSummary ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= PROVISIONING_PROFILE=
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable Build for Running and Archiving for the Test Target in App's scheme for the Plugins folder to show up with the xctest directory.

```
<BuildActionEntry
 buildForTesting = "YES"
 buildForRunning = "YES"
 buildForProfiling = "NO"
 buildForArchiving = "YES"
 buildForAnalyzing = "NO">
 <BuildableIdentifier = "primary"
 ...
   BuildableName = "AppNameTests.xctest"
   BlueprintName = "AppNameTests"
 ...
 </BuildableReference>
</BuildActionEntry>
```